# Setting the Control in RadGrid to Visible-False

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I need help with getting the ID of the Control in RadGrid in order to set it Visable=False.

The last function is actually creating a pic based on the value that's coming from the DB. How can I set the HyperLink next to the Pic that I'm adding to Visible false?

I think that I need to send that function RenderLinked the hyperlink control but I don't know how and I hope that some one can show me the way.

```
<telerik:RadGrid
    ID="rgPhoneBook"
    runat="server"              
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AllowPaging="True"
    AllowSorting="True"
    PageSize="50" 
    CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" 
    OnItemCommand="rgPhoneBook_ItemCommand"
    OnPageIndexChanged="rgPhoneBook_OnPageIndexChanged"
    OnSortCommand="rgPhoneBook_OnSortCommand"
    OnItemCreated="rgPhoneBook_OnItemCreated"
    EnableHeaderContextFilterMenu="True"
    Width="933px" 
    Height="528px">
    <ClientSettings>
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="true" FrozenColumnsCount="2" />              
    </ClientSettings>  
    <MasterTableView ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true" NoMasterRecordsText="No PhoneBook Records to display" Font-Size="11px" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" ItemStyle-Height="25px" CommandItemDisplay="Top" AllowAutomaticUpdates="False" TableLayout="Auto" DataKeyNames="LocationID,PersonID" ClientDataKeyNames="LocationID,PersonID">
        <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Linked"  HeaderStyle-Width="45px" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <span id="spanHyperLink" style="visibility:visible" runat="server">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="Link" runat="server" Text="Link">
                        </asp:HyperLink>
                    </span>
                    <%# RenderLinked(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Linked"))%> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>


Protected Function RenderLinked(ByVal inputVal As String) As String
    Dim output As String = ""
    Try
        Dim svcs As New SystemServices
        If Not inputVal Is Nothing And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputVal) Then
            If inputVal = True Then
                output = "<img src='" + Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("\Images\Layout\Link.png") + "' width=""13"" height=""13"" border=""0"" align=""absmiddle"">"
            Else
                'Dim item As GridDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)
                'Dim link As HyperLink = DirectCast(item("Link").Controls(0), HyperLink)
                'LinkButton.DisabledCssClass = True
                Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "StartupScript", "Sys.Application.add_load(function() { DisableHyperLinkCSS();  });", True)

                'output = "<a herf='#' onclick='showPersonLinkModal() ;'>Link</a>"
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Globals.SendEmailError(ex, m_User.SessionID, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name.ToString(), Request.RawUrl.ToString(), m_User.UserID)
    End Try
Return output
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set some control's attribute `visible=false` in code behind when rows are bound to data 1 by 1 you may use `RowDataBound` event and write following code in it's handler

```
Control_Type Control_ID = (Control_Type) e.Row.FindControl("Control_ID");
Control_ID.Visible = false;
```

And if you want to set it in javascript,

```
rgPhoneBook.Rows[Record_Index].Cells[0].Visible = false;
```

Hope this helps you. The above code is in C#, please convert it to it's equivalent in VB.

Comment: Thank you for your help this is what I wrote: but still not working! its marking e.Row as an error="e is not declared it may be inaccessible due its protection level"   Dim link As HyperLink = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("Link"), HyperLink)
                    link.Visible = False  Do I need to send something to that RenderLinked function????